# Why is there always error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported on laravel 6 using laragon?

Tags: laravel, laravel-6

When I write the command npm install && npm run dev it always appears like this

Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported

Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported

```
at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
```

opensslErrorStack: [ 'error:03000086:digital envelope routines::initialization error' ],
library: 'digital envelope routines',
reason: 'unsupported',
code: 'ERR_OSSL_EVP_UNSUPPORTED'
}

Node.js v18.8.0

```
Making my first laravel 6 by using laragon and fron-end vue
```

Comment: This error mostly appears due to an unsupported node version. Try to downgrade the node to 16 or update webpack and other packages to support the updated node version.

Comment: How? @AnujShrestha

Answer (score 0):

I'm too faced the same issue,You can either use 1st or 2nd method,

1. Just downgrade the node version in to Node v16 just run:
   nvm install 16
   or
   2.If you have multiple versions of Node.js installed on your workspace
   nvm use v16.13.2